# Is ExecutorCompletionService thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, blockingqueue

I understand that `ExecutorCompletionService` depends on `BlockingQueue` for thread-safety:

from `BlockingQueue` JavaDoc:

> BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods
>   achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms
>   of concurrency control.

However, the `ExecutorCompletionService` has a constructor that accepts an arbitrary implementation of the `BlockingQueue`, which might not be a thread safe.

Does this make `ExecutorCompletionService` compromised for being thread unsafe?

Comment: Any implementation of BLockingQueue MUST respect the javadoc's contract. If it fails to do so, then in turn, ExecutorCompletionService may also fail consequently. But more broadly, if you start thinking that implementations fail to respect their contracts, they who is to say your CPU, or your RAM, or your OS, or the JVM, or the java.lang.Thread, or actually ANYTHING works at all... The doc says "blocking queues are be thread safe".  If they're not, it's their bug, not ExecutorCompletionServce's.

Comment: Thread safety only applies if you do not call "alien methods" (JCIP). If you don't know what is being passed in, you cannot know if your code is thread safe. If this is the scenario you are in, it would be the fault of the implementor rather than in Java (or yourself if you are not the author of that code).